# генерация последовательностей чисел

Tags: c#, теория-вероятностей

Необходимо генерировать 2 последовательности чисел:
1-ая должна быть распределена по равномерному закону
2-ая по гауссовскому
Есть или в с# встроенные функции для этого или описание написания таких функций?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По поводу равномерного распределения, всё просто.

Заводите генератор случайных чисел:

```
Random r = new Random();
```

(в .NET Framework по многим причинам лучше положить его в статическую переменную, а ещё лучше — в зависящую от потока).

Теперь `r.NextDouble()` даст вам случайную величину, равномерно распределённую между 0 и 1. Чтобы получить равномерное распределение на отрезке `[a, b]`, используйте, понятно, `r.NextDouble() * (b - a) + a`.

Для того, чтобы сгенерировать нормальное распределение с μ = 0 и σ = 1 (то есть, стандартную нормальную величину), можно воспользоваться алгоритмом Марсальи. Поскольку он выдаёт два значения, одно придётся хранить в объекте.

```
class NormalRandom : Random
{
    // сохранённое предыдущее значение
    double prevSample = double.NaN;
    protected override double Sample()
    {
        // есть предыдущее значение? возвращаем его
        if (!double.IsNaN(prevSample))
        {
            double result = prevSample;
            prevSample = double.NaN;
            return result;
        }

        // нет? вычисляем следующие два
        // Marsaglia polar method из википедии
        double u, v, s;
        do
        {
            u = 2 * base.Sample() - 1;
            v = 2 * base.Sample() - 1; // [-1, 1)
            s = u * u + v * v;
        }
        while (u <= -1 || v <= -1 || s >= 1 || s == 0);
        double r = Math.Sqrt(-2 * Math.Log(s) / s);

        prevSample = r * v;
        return r * u;
    }
}
```

Этим классом можно пользоваться так же, как и `Random`:

```
NormalRandom nr = new NormalRandom();
// ...
double x = nr.NextDouble();
```

Если нужно получить нормальное распределение с другими μ и σ, применяйте скалирование:

```
double x = nr.NextDouble() * deviation + expectation;
```

([Учтите](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.sample%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Anchor_1), что при этом `nr.Next()` и т. п. будут всё ещё пользоваться равномерным распределением, так что если надо, переопределите и другие методы.)

Answer (score 1):

Равномерное распределение — класс `Random`.
Гауссово — встроенной возможности нет, можно написать самому. Примеры есть здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218060/random-gaussian-variables