# Как создать полет слегка отклоненный от цели выстрел из оружия AI от его цели

Tags: c#, unity3d

Полет пули к цели с практически одинаковой скоростью осуществляется с помощью данного скрипта:

```
public class RedBullet : MonoBehaviour
{
public Vector3 direction;
public Vector3 step;
public float speed;
public float katetX;
public float katetY;
public float gipotenuza;
public float bulletSpeed = 20f;

void Start()
{
    direction = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform.position;
    katetX = direction.x - transform.position.x;
    katetY = direction.y - transform.position.y;
    gipotenuza = Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(katetX, 2) + Mathf.Pow(katetY, 2));
    step = new Vector3(katetX/(gipotenuza * bulletSpeed),katetY/(gipotenuza * bulletSpeed),1);
}

void Update()
{
    transform.position += step;
}
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("BulletWall"))
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        // play destroy anim
    }
}
}
```

Возможно, можно сделать полет снаряда проще, например с помощью `Raycast2D`, если это правда, то мне хотелось бы узнать как. В любом случае мне нужно, чтобы снаряды летели не только прямо в объект с тегом `player`, но и на `n` градусов правее и левее от него, как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом первом шаге определяем направление оружие-цель

```
midAngle = atan2(direction.y - transform.position.y, direction.x - transform.position.x);
```

и производим, например, отклонение этого угла с нормальным распределением

```
devAngle = randG(midAngle, stdDev);
```

где randG даёт гауссово распределение с заданным средним и среднеквадратичным отклонением. [Например, вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218060/random-gaussian-variables) или [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/491105/%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB)- но, может, в мат библиотеках шарпа что-то готовое появилось с тех пор.

Теперь перерассчитаем целевую позицию с новым углом (эквивалентно ошибке прицеливания),

```
direction.x = Дистанция * cos(devAngle)
direction.y = Дистанция * sin(devAngle)
```

и в дальнейшем для расчёта шага будем использовать смещенную позицию